# Динамический фильтр товаров в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице каталога товаров есть фильтры, которык помогают отсеять товары: цвет, размер, категория, сезон и т.д.

Как фильтровать саму выборку товаров я знаю. не могу понять как обновить сам фильтр слева чтобы он, основываясь на текущем выборе пользователя, подставлял ему для выбора только те варианты выбора в фильтре, которые вернут результат (хотя бы 1 товар).

Например, пользователь выбрал в меню фильтра категорию куртки и размер М.

Нужно чтобы кроме выборки товаров обновились и варианты выбора других фильтров. Сейчас нам нужны куртки размера м, если в фильтре выбора сезона есть варианты, в которых нет курток размера м, то чтобы они скрывались. и так по всем фильтрам.

Comment: Примерно как тут https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74896/woocommerce-product-category-widget-hide-categories-that-have-no-products-in-s

Comment: @labris увы, там совсем не то, что нужно.Фильтр состоит из таксономий и доп.полей. так вот скрыть нужно неактивные опции фильтра для текущей выборки